# Unable to connect to Firestore via iOS Simulator on Apple Silicon

Tags: ios, apple-silicon

I'm trying to access my Firestore instance using my M1 MacBook Air, with no luck. Trying to access via the iOS simulator gives the following response:

```
2021-01-20 09:18:11.747682-0500 TestApp[81986:3364534] 7.4.0 - [Firebase/Firestore][I-FST000001] WatchStream (600000541718) Stream error: 'Unavailable: Network connectivity changed'

2021-01-20 09:18:11.748325-0500 TestApp[81986:3364534] 7.4.0 - [Firebase/Firestore][I-FST000001] Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Connection failed 1 times. Most recent error: Network connectivity changed
 This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will operate in offline mode until it is able to successfully connect to the backend.
```

The odd thing is that it did connect one time - although this was many times ago. It was able to pull a snapshot of the small dataset I had. However, it never connected again, and even when I changed the data, nothing happened. I'm assuming because it was cached.

I am able to access Safari and websites via the simulator, so I don't believe it's an actual network issue.

A look at how I'm calling Firestore below:

```
    Firestore.firestore().collection("companies").getDocuments{(snapshot, error) in
            if error == nil {
                for document in snapshot!.documents {
                    let name = document.data()["name"] as? String
                    print(name)
                }
            } else {
                print(error ?? "Unknown Error")
            }
        }
```

A look at my Podfile below:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Sesame' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Sesame
  pod 'Firebase/Firestore', '7.4-M1'
  pod 'Firebase/Storage', '7.4-M1'
  target 'SesameTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'SesameUITests' do
    # Pods for testing
  end
  post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH'] = 'YES'
      end
"Podfile" 26L, 654C
```

Any ideas where I should look to fix this connection issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering my own question for any who may come across this - I "solved" this issue. I had to use my own iPhone and deploy the code to that device, where it ran fine. I suppose this is an iOS simulator bug, specifically on Apple Silicon right now.